# MS Access glitch - dataform view is showing incorrect values

Tags: sql, ms-access, ssms

See attached picture. I've filtered the form by ProjectNo = 28341, but the record that returns has ProjectNo = 16424. I've checked the backend and found two records with the above project numbers and the same address, but I don't see how this could have occurred. When the view is sorted by ProjectNo in MSAccess, the ProjectNo column shows 28342, 16424, 28340, so it appears that MSAccess knows what the correct ProjectNo is and is for some reason refusing to show it.

Any idea what the problem might be?

[Filtered view and incorrect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjPa1.png)

[ssms query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQj0J.png)

[view structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3pY9.png)

Comment: What is field data type for `ProjectNo`? Share table structure.

Comment: @Harun24hr Edited the question with view structure.

Comment: So, you are using link table or using pass through query? May SQL driver problem. Try to use update SQL ODBC driver.

Comment: That seems to be it, thanks. I tested it on ODBC Driver 18 and it's fixed.

Comment: I have posted it as answer so that you can accept (tick mark the answer) it.

Comment: @Harun24hr Unfortunately after updating all my users that didn't work. The same problem appears regardless of which ODBC driver I use (17 or 18)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since found the answer - the problem is that when linking MS Access to SQL Server, a prompt appears asking for the unique record identifier. I selected the wrong field, which caused incorrect behavior.

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems you are using link table or pass-through query. I assume problem is causing due to `ODBC` driver for SQL Server. Use updated SQL-ODBC driver and problem should solve.

Check from Microsoft [Download ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16).